# Can I make an ender portal on creative?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've updated Minecraft PE, and in the update notes it states that they've added the End. But when I made a new creative world and built a portal, it didn't work.

I've been looking online at tutorials, but cannot get the portal to open. So how do you create an Ender Portal?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your end portal looks like? We didn't watch the same videos or read the same things as you, so it's hard for us to tell you what the problem is.

Comment: It should work just fine, make sure that the portal blocks are placed correctly. You must be inside where you want the portal to be, looking outwards, when placing the blocks.

Comment: I did it like the things showed... nothing works.

Comment: @Maddie what things? Can you link some of what you watched?

Comment: Well... I don't remember who I watched... I read some articles,watched some YouTube videos. They all showed the same thing.

Comment: Ummmmm. Well... I do know most said the same things, websites and YouTube

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't do it at first either, but I figured it out: You need to stand **inside** of the portal whilst putting in the eye of enders. If you stand anywhere else but inside of it, it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

To create an end portal, you need to make a 3x3 circle of end portal blocks. Then, take away the edges and fill in the rest with eyes of ender. The problem that most people have with making end portals, is that they get the placement wrong.

You can place end portals so that they are vertical or horizontal. Here is an image of one:
[image: Image of End Portal (Taken from Minecraft Gamepedia)]
If you look at the front of one of the blocks, you can see that it has a little 'u' shape. You want to make sure that it points toward the middle. You can do this by facing the middle of where you want to make your portal, and then move to the sides of it whenever you finish a line of blocks.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

Yes, with commands you should be able to (at least in the PC version).

**Long answer:**

To make an Ender Portal in Minecraft Pocket Edition in creative mode without finding a stronghold, you need to use a command. I am pretty sure they did not add that command. The command used to be `/setblock ~ ~ ~ end_gateway` in beta build 1, but it no longer works with the official release.

**Alternatives:**

I have tried building it again and again in MCPE, but it would not fill the middle witht the block `end_gateway`. I tried it with all eyes facing in, I have tried it with all of them facing side- to side, I have tried one of them opposite of the other, I have tried placing them all the same way to the world. None of those worked. I even ied following https://www.digminecraft.com/getting_started/how_to_make_end_portal.php

So the only way you can get to the End in Creative without commands is to find a find an End Portal in a stronghold, it should be a lot easier in creative rather than survival.

Here are some helpful links to finding a Stronghold:

and 
http://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-End-Portal-in-Minecraft

Answer (score 0):

To make an end portal you need the end portal frames to be pointing outwards from the center meaning you have to stand in the middle and make sure none of the end portal frames are pointing towards you or to the side then get eyes of ender and put the on the end portal frame and that should work :D

Answer (score -1):

It's none of what you've guys have said lol. It's to do with the pattern of the Portal itself. Make sure the green tabs are facing In.

Check this link https://www.digminecraft.com/getting_started/how_to_make_end_portal.php

Comment: You should include relevant parts from that link in case the link ever dies in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Portals are a bit glitchy. I'd recommend just using endereyes to find a stronghold.

[image]

Comment: This was the case until a few days ago, but The End update was released 19 Dec 2016: http://toucharcade.com/2016/12/19/ender-update-1-0-just-brought-dragons-music-and-more-to-minecraft-pocket-edition/

Answer (score -3):

Sure! Just go in the command box type'/setblock ~ ~ ~ endportal' and u would be good to go! But, I'm not sure if it'll spawn there. It just sends u there... to the end.

Comment: While this would indeed get him to the End, it's through console commands. He asked how to build the portal, not how to teleport there